# Can node webkit build in a single windows .exe file

Tags: node-webkit, autorun, usb-drive

I have a project that need to run in a pen drive, the content is updated daily, and i need a automated way to generate a single file (.exe) to be downloaded by users.

I use this tool https://github.com/mllrsohn/node-webkit-builder, but when build for windows, the build generate multiple files ( dlls, dat ,exe ).

This break my automation because the content need to be downloaded (single file).

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, it can't. You could try making a [7zip SFX archive](http://7zip.bugaco.com/7zip/MANUAL/switches/sfx.htm) and running your own program instead of an installer.

This needs to create temporal files when run (which are deleted when the program quits) and I don't think you can remove the initial prompt. If you're okay with that, it might be what you need.

Edit: You can get [the necessary SFX modules here](http://www.7zsfx.info/en/).